# How to get patient records from EPIC FHIR with just telecom as query string

Tags: hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir, smart-on-fhir, hl7-fhir

I am trying to search FHIR data from EPIC system by connecting to FHIR sandbox. I just wanted to pull all patient records with just telecom (phone or email) like GET [base]/Patient?telecom=abc@email.com. But it looks like EPIC retrieves results only after appending family, gender, name as additional query parameters. How can I retrieve the record with just telecom as query parameter. I tried other options such as _text and contains but still it is not retrieving any results.

Answer (score 0):

Servers don't have to support cross-patient queries, and many of the EHR's initial FHIR interfaces are patient-centric.  For security and privacy reasons they require a certain minimum set of search information to use when looking up a patient to verify them - and then require the patient id when searching other resources.  You can certainly talk to them and ask them to extend their interface to do what you want at some point in the future, but for now, you're going to be limited to the search constraints they've baked into their interface.